# How to make tests for react & django web-application

Tags: reactjs, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

- Is there a specific way to make tests if you are using Django with react? or do I just test them separately?
- Is there any open source web site on GitHub/gitlab using react and Django as backend that I can use as reference? (I want to look at real code not just example codes)